# Can't figure out if is correct to use this type of variables in linear regression

Tags: regression, linear

Let say we have a variable X1 that measure the percentage of C from total population and X2 as a variable that measure the growth rate of C in t,t+1 period. I wonder if is correct to use both variables in the same linear regression  I am still studying statistics, so any explanation would be a real help for me! Thanks!

PS: for example x1 is mortality rate of men and x2 is annual rate growth of men mortality